# How to map property to first of many in Fluent NHibernate?

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

Given a parent child relationship between `User` and `FailedLogin` where a user has many failed logins.  I'd like to map this into

```
class User
{
    public virtual FailedLogin LastFailedLogin { get; set; }
}

class FailedLogin
{
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime AttemptOn { get; set; }
}
```

So that the `LastFailedLogin` property contains the `FailedLogin` with the most recent `AttemptOn` date and time.  If `LastFailedLogin` is set it should save that `FailedLogin` to the database (i.e. `.Cascade.SaveUpdate()`)  Note, **I do not want to map a collection of all FailedLogins for this user for performance reasons**.

I have been totally unable to write a fluent mapping for this.  How do I map this using Fluent NHibernate?

```
public class UserMap : ClassMap<User>
{
    public UserMap()
    {
        // What goes here for LastFailedLogin?
    }
}

public class FailedLoginMap: ClassMap<FailedLogin>
{
    public FailedLoginMap()
    {
        References(x => x.User).Not.Update();
        Map(x => x.AttemptOn).Not.Update();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I settled on, which I'm not entirely happy with, is:

```
public class User
{
    private readonly IList failedLogins;
    public virtual FailedLogin LastFailedLogin
    {
        get
        {
            return failedLogins.FirstOrDefault();
        }
        set
        {
            failedLogins.Clear();
            failedLogins.Add(value);
        }
    }
}

public class UserMap : ClassMap<User>
{
    HasMany(Reveal.Member<User, IEnumerable<FailedLogin>>("failedLogins"))
        .Where("FailedLoginID=(SELECT TOP 1 a.FailedLoginID FROM FailedLogin AS a " + 
                "WHERE a.UserID = UserID ORDER BY a.AttemptOn DESC)")
        .Cascade.SaveUpdate().Access.CamelCaseField().Inverse();
}
```

This solution ensures that only a single `FailedLogin` is loaded with the `User`.   It also handles correctly saving a new failed login that is associated to the user. Finally it ensures that the implementation is hidden from consumers of the `User` class. Unfortunately,  this still imposes persistence concerns on the `User` class.

Answer (score 0):

i cant see a direct solution but there would be with an internal list:

```
class User
{
    internal virtual IList<FailedLogin> LastFailedLogins { get; set; }
    public virtual FailedLogin LastFailedLogin { get { LastFailedLogins.FirstOrDefault(); } set { LastFailedLogins.Insert(0, value); } }
}

public class UserMap : ClassMap<User>
{
    public UserMap()
    {
        HasMany(u => u.LastFailedLogins)
            .OrderBy("AttemptOn desc");
    }
}
```

Comment: What I don't like about this answer is that it loads all failed logins which is a potentially large collection, especially since a user is loaded on every web request.